# left align text in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css, text-align

```
.equiv {
  margin: auto;
  display: table;
}
.equiv .eso {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

I use those styles in order to align center the container .equiv, and keep its contents (in .eso) left aligned:

```
<div class="equiv">
  <div class="eso">
    <p>Consider this text<br>
      as a verse of a poem<br>
      that is left aligned<br>
      but in the middle of the page.</p>
    <p>(The middle of the page<br>
      corresponds to the middle<br>
      of the largest line of course).</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

well, it works in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Explorer, where the text is simply left aligned (but not in the middle).
Is there a workaround?

Comment: it seems to be working for me in all three browsers (http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/434/). what version of ie are you using?

Comment: @indubitablee Hmm. It seems that you've right. When I test just the code it's ok. When I test it along with other elements in the page it doesn't work. I have to look deeper... Thanks

Comment: Could you let me know what is missing in my answer?, so I can adjust and you accept.

Answer (score 0):

That's quite simple actually and you have all the wrappers you need.

```
.equiv {
  text-align: center;
}
.eso {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: left;
}
```